# Fonts that look alike as text and as math

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif

What fonts give similar look when used as text and within math environment?

I'm particularly interested in sans serif fonts, but serif fonts are also very welcomed.

Comment: Well, I hope *no* font fulfills that demand.

Comment: "Look alike" is difficult to quantify, since math is typically in italic, whereas text is not.  There are, however, some math fonts that are "paired" to a text font.  That doesn't mean they look alike, but rather provide some ineffable quality that makes the effect pleasing.  One example is Palatino (text) and the Euler fonts (eulervm package for math).

Comment: [Fonts with math support](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html)

Comment: @MichaelHoppe The default serif font does. Most importantly, digits looks alike in both cases. When, say, a table contains both text and math-enclosed digits, they really appears the same.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Maybe better `eulervm` package, IIRC

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The euler fonts are somewhat ... upright.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  True, but I believe I heard that Zapf (the font designer) proposed those as paired.

Comment: @Anton After your comment, the question seems to make no sense. The default LaTeX font -- Computer/Latin Modern -- satisfies the condition that they "look alike", because they are simply the same. If you want to use the sans-serif variant, just do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}\usepackage{sfmath}\let\familydefault\sfdefault`

Comment: @Anton Don't we want the mathematical part of our works to appear typographically different to the non-mathematical content? This clearly would increase the readability of our works. So we *must* demand that those two parts are typed somewhat different.

Comment: As tohecz says, digits in math in the standard setup come from the document roman font. so digits in text and math are identical, you don't require two fonts with similar digits.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe in the standard latex setup digits and `\log`-like command names all come from the document roman text font, so it certainly isn't always the case that you want different glyphs in the two cases.

Comment: @tohecz Your code is exactly what I needed. I would gladly accept it as the answer, if you added it below. (Thanks everyone for a useful discussion.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is as clear as ice, but how mercilessly is f(x):=2x+3 compared to $f(x):=2x+3$?  Mr Carlisle, known as  one of the all-time heroes of the TeX-community, known to me since decade(s): you've just quoted a useful exception which is used to enhance readability. -- But we don't want -- for the sake of that readability -- to have *all* mathematical glyphs look like the document's roman fonts, do we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I don't think that this is a good idea, and if the document *has* to be typeset in sans-serif, I would personally prefer to have the math in serif, you can add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % font encoding (not completely necessary)
\usepackage{lmodern} % Latin Modern (not completely necessary)
\usepackage{sfmath} % use sans-serif math font
\let\familydefau‌​lt\sfdefault % use sans-serif text font
```